# Getting a domain name from a squatter when I have no trademark?

Tags: domain, domain-name

I am going to start a website for a blog and my profession. I am not a business and have not registered a business. I have no patents or trademarks.

Basically, I'm an individual.
However, my ideal choice of domain name is taken by huge domains.com. I think they are what you'd call cybersquatters? It's not just I who has major issues with their business model.

They own thousands of domains simply to profit off them when people like me need them.
My question is how can I get the domain off them? They are asking for $2100 which is frankly ridiculous.
I have heard of certain solutions, but they seem to be oriented towards those with trademarks or businesses registered with a name which the cybersqautters have nicked.

I just want to make clear a couple of points:

- Please don't tell me to get a different domain name. I am trying to get this domain off hugedomains.com, not prefix my desired name with 'the' or 'my'.
- The domain I want is a .com gTLD
- I do not wish to haggle with hugedomains.com

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/how-to-register-a-trade-mark

Comment: Cybersquatting [would be registering a domain for an *existing* trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting). It's not squatting if you just came up with the company name and domain just now - they thought of it before you did! You have no right to the domain; if it's not worth $2100 to you, pick another.

Answer (score 2):

From a legal point, you have no right to request that domain even after getting trademark since they are the owner before you registered the trademark. So your only chance is waiting if they renew the registration or buying the domain from them.

From the business point, I can generate domain names that will be probably registered from existing domains and registering them and then reselling them at price. That is a totally valid business plan.